# How to re-use groups of tests in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm working on a wizard-style application using AngularJS, and using ProtractorJS for E2E testing. I've defined PageObjects representing various screens and objects on the page.

In writing e2e tests for the app, I've noticed that several of the tests move through several wizard pages in the same way, and I'd like to define reusable sets of tests that I could invoke as part of larger test suites. I've attempted to do this by creating functions which have a describe(... it (...); it(...)) sequence inside but my issue is passing a reference to the new PageObject out of the function, since the test suites are executed after the function has already returned.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, cant you just reuse functions and juts have expects? we do something similar, where we have multiple tests that need to perform similar/the same actions multiple times, we just have expects to make sure everything is working fine along the way before we get to the actual main purpose of the test.